# Laravel 5.8 Class 'Form' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using `laravel 5.8` and trying to use `Form` and when I load the page it outputs the error: `class Form not found`. Is there a way to fix this in `version 5.8` I've searched for solutions and all I can find is a fix for other versions.

Thanks!

Comment: The `Form` was removed from Laravel in version 5.0. The answer below should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use LaravelCollective Form. If so, you have to add it with composer. Check the documentation [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.8/html).